# Mover apenas parte de um texto para outra coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

Tenho uma planilha conforme anexo que na coluna logradouro encontra-se o endereço e o numero, porém, eu quero separar, ou seja,retirar o numero dos endereços que encontram-se na coluna logradouro e mover para coluna numero de uma vez só. Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
Logradouro                                  Numéro (Essa coluna nao tem nada)

AV NOSSA SENHORA DE COPACABANA 664  
AV DOM SEVERINO     
AV GETULIO VARGAS   
AV TANCREDO NEVES 148   
AV DOM HELDER CAMARA, 5332  
AV TANCREDO NEVES 148   
R PROJETADA 05 S/N  
ROD BA-526 305  
AV MAGALHAES DE CASTRO 12000
```

Comment: é possível passar a planilha pra csv ? se sim, pode utilizar o notepad++ que é muiito mais simples de fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo dependende de como está padronizado seus dados, mas se os números estiverem sempre nas últimas posições como no seu exemplo:

```
AV NOSSA SENHORA DE COPACABANA 664  
AV DOM SEVERINO     
AV DOM HELDER CAMARA, 5332  
R PROJETADA 05 S/N  
ROD BA-526 305
```

Poderia usar um conjunto de funções para alcançar o que deseja, algo assim:

```
=SE(ÉERRO(VALOR(DIREITA(A1;CORRESP(" "; ÍNDICE(EXT.TEXTO(A1;NÚM.CARACT(A1)-LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&NÚM.CARACT(A1)))+1;1);0);0)-1)));"S/N";VALOR(DIREITA(A1;CORRESP(" "; ÍNDICE(EXT.TEXTO(A1;NÚM.CARACT(A1)-LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&NÚM.CARACT(A1)))+1;1);0);0)-1)))
```

> Esta é a fórmula completa, veja mais abaixo como cheguei à essa fórmula.

É um pouco longa o conjunto de fórmulas... mas é simples, vou tentar separar e explicar para compreender melhor:

1. Verifica o primeiro espaço da *direita* para a *esquerda*, pois pelos dados que forneceu os últimos caracteres são seus números, e alguns possuem "S/N" outros estão sem nenhum número, então seria:

   ```
   =CORRESP(" "; ÍNDICE(EXT.TEXTO(A1;NÚM.CARACT(A1)-LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&NÚM.CARACT(A1)))+1;1);0);0)
   ```

> Esta é a fórmula mais difícil de entender de fato.

2. Busca os dados da direita para esquerda após o último espaço em branco:

   ```
   =DIREITA(A1;[FÓRMULA DO ITEM 1 AQUI]-1)
   ```

> Substituir o que está entre **[ ]** (colchetes) pela fórmula do item 1.

3. Verirfica se esse resultado (item 2) é um número e retorna esse número ou retorna um texto ("S/N" no caso):

   ```
   =SE(ÉERRO(VALOR([FÓRMULA DO ITEM 2 E 1]));"S/N";VALOR([FÓRMULA DO ITEM 2 E 1]))
   ```

> Substituir o que está entre **[ ]** (colchetes) pela fórmula do item 2 e item 1 para ter a fórmula completa.

Faça um teste com a fórmula completa em um aplanilha tendo o endereço na célula "A1" e verá que funciona.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma função em VBA para o Excel:

```
Function StripNumber(stdText As String) 
    Dim str As String, i As Integer 
     'strips the number from a longer text string
    stdText = Trim(stdText) 

    For i = 1 To Len(stdText) 
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(stdText, i, 1)) Then 
            str = str & Mid(stdText, i, 1) 
        End If 
    Next i 

    StripNumber = str ' * 1

End Function
```

[Aqui](https://guiadoexcel.com.br/como-criar-funcoes-proprias-no-excel-com-vba/) tem um tutorial de cadastrar funções VBA no Excel

Ou podes usar essa "gambiarra":

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,"")